# Kinect: how do I convert depth image to pointcloud?

Tags: ros, kinect, wireless

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to send kinect data wirelessly to a desktop computer. Point clouds consume a lot of bandwidth, so I want to send the depth images instead. But on my desktop computer, what is the easiest way to convert those depth images into point clouds? Do I have to make my own node and just grab the correct point cloud functions out of the kinect driver or has someone already done that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27921/kinect:-how-do-i-convert-depth-image-to-pointcloud?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There also now appears to be a new package [depth_image_proc](http://ros.org/wiki/depth_image_proc) in the image_pipeline stack for Fuerte that will take a Kinect uint16 image and transforms it into a point cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [huangzonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/36659/huangzonghao/) on 2018-07-27**:
are there any tutorials on that package? I have been trying so hard to find a way to use that package on my rosbag data, but still got no luck. Really frustrated

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [openni_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) driver provides that functionality. It's broken up in nodelets - some are responsible for publishing the images, and some for processing them and assembling point clouds.

Normally, you start one nodelet manager, and all nodelets together on the same machine. In your use case, you would have to start two nodelet managers - one on for each machine on the end of the WiFi connection.

I had set up some launch files for a similar purpose a while back. You can find them here:

http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/data/kinect/launch_modular/

The openni_driver file is responsible for publishsing the image data, and the opneni_proc file is responsible for assembling it to 3D. They were set up for a single nodelet manager, so you would have to modify that.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-26**:
I found the documentation for the [nodelets](http://ros.org/wiki/depth_image_proc) but haven't had time yet to try them with your launch files ... thanks!

**Comment by [lisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27696/lisa/) on 2016-08-16**:
Unfortunately the URL http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/data/kinect/launch_modular/ is broken